# Excel - create column with blank cells if a cell is repeated and use it as dependency for a second column

Tags: excel, dynamic-tables

As I am pretty inexperienced with Excel, I am struggling with the following situation.
In a sheet I have the following columns

```
Account  Investment  
1        a  
2        b  
3        c  
1        d  
2        e 
1        a
```

My desired output, in a different sheet, should be something like this

```
AccountAc      InvestmentAc  
1              a
               d
2              b
               e
3              c
```

I have this formula for AccountAc `=IFERROR(IF(InvInformation[Account]=$A2, "", INDEX(InvInformation[Account], MATCH(0, FREQUENCY(IF(EXACT(InvInformation[Account], TRANSPOSE($A$2:$A2)), MATCH(ROW(InvInformation[Account]), ROW(InvInformation[Account])), ""), MATCH(ROW(InvInformation[Account]), ROW(InvInformation[Account]))), 0))), "")`

And in InvestmentAc `=IFERROR((INDEX(InvInformation[Investment], MATCH(2, (COUNTIF($B$2:$B2, InvInformation[Investment])+(InvInformation[Account]=[@AccountAc]))+(COUNTIF($B$2:$B2, InvInformation[Investment])+(InvInformation[Actual]=1)), 0), COLUMN(A1))), "")`
(InvInformation is the able containing Account and Investment)

Which returns this result

```
AccountAc     InvestmentAc  
1             a  

2             b
3             c
```

I know why the value "d" is skipped for InvestmentAc (as it points out to @AccountAc which is empty)

Note: the resulting table has to be dynamic. When more data is added to Account and Investment, the resulting table expands as well.

Does anybody have an idea on how I can get the desired result and to point to a non-blank cell in InvestmentAc? All this has to be done without VBA, only formulas.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do on that is set up a sort with Account as the first criterion and Investment as the second sort criterion. Then I'd deal with the duplicates in the Account column.  To remove them, you could then create a third column that looks the cells above and sets duplicates to blank using a simple IF statement.

Comment: This method won't work. I just tried applying a sort and it actually deleted info in one cell. Even if it wouldn't delete, I would still face the blank-cells problem (I need a formula in the entire AccountAc column to do the job

Comment: Thinking about that.  A sort shouldn't delete anything if done properly. In many many years with Excel, I've never seen that. Maybe you could check help on how to do a sort.

Comment: I've done it wit a bit of help, that was the result. Possibly I may have messed something up. Found a solution to it anyway, but thanks for your input :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a pivot table with both AccountAc and InvestmentAc in rows, with no totals.